# How to properly write a template wrapper response class with void return type

Tags: c++, templates, try-catch

I want to write a wrapper class that call a function, so that

- If the function successfully exit, then store the result in wrapper's `data` field
- Otherwise, convert the exception to an `int` error code.

Here's what I have:

```
struct ResponseBase
{
    int code = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Response : ResponseBase
{
    T data;
};

template<>
struct Response<void> : ResponseBase {
};

template<typename F>
auto try_catch_wrapper(F&& f)
{
    Response<decltype(f())> res;
    try
    {
        res.data = f(); // here's the problem
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        res.code = -1;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    auto a = try_catch_wrapper([]() {
        return 1;
        });

    if (a.code == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Invoke Success, Result: " << a.data << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Code: " << a.code << std::endl;
    }

    // won't work for void return type
    //auto b = try_catch_wrapper([]() {
    //    return;
    //    });
}
```

Comment: Your function returns a `void`, so your wrapper is going to use your `void` specialization, which does not have the `data` member.   Templates are not dynamic -- `res` must be the same type throughout any single instantiation.  `res` can't change types in the middle.

Comment: This seems more like a design problem. You have to decide what you want to happen in the `void` case. As `Response<void>` doesn't have a `data` member, you get the mentioned error.

Comment: So should I write a `void` specialization of `try_catch_wrapper`? But that would result in most of the wrapper code same as the generic one. In my case, I just want to call `f()`.

Comment: @EricQiang You can add a `constexpr if` as done in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sbG9nG8v8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to call f()

You can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) as shown below:

```
template<typename F>
auto try_catch_wrapper(F&& f)
{
    Response<decltype(f())> res;
    try
    { 
        //added this constexpr if
        if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<decltype(f()), void>)
        {
                res.data = f();
        }
        else
        {
            f();
        }
        
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        res.code = -1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jfecEbjj4)

Comment: Is it safe to use `#pragma warning(disable : 4984)`? Because the meaning of this wrapper is to supply a DLL interface for a C++14 legacy project which I cannot control.

Comment: @EricQiang For any follow up question(that is different from the original question), feel free to ask a new separate question.

Answer (score 0):

A C++14 version would be to have the 2 overloads with SFINAE:

```cpp
template<typename F,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<F>()()), void>::value, bool> = false>
auto try_catch_wrapper(F&& f)
{
    Response<decltype(f())> res;
    try
    { 
        f();
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        res.code = -1;
    }
    return res;
}

template<typename F,
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<F>()()), void>::value, bool> = false>
auto try_catch_wrapper(F&& f)
{
    Response<decltype(f())> res;
    try
    { 
        res.data = f(); // here's the problem
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        res.code = -1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/36z17s1Kh)

Comment: I'm new to SFINAE. Can you give some further explanation on `enable_if_t<..., bool> = false`? I search some other posts, and see another way `enable_if_t<..., int> = 1`. I guess both of you are correct and doing the same thing.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae