# MSVC compiler warning c4984

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

I'm trying to implement a DLL and offer some interfaces to a legacy VS2017 C++14 project which I cannot control. ([Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77505670/how-to-properly-write-a-template-wrapper-response-class-with-void-return-type)).
I want to use `if constexpr` expression in my header files, and found the compiler would complain about [C4984](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-c4984). Not sure what is the meaning "portable":

> If you require C++11 or C++14 compatibility, this expression isn't portable.

> C4984 is issued as an error by default, but it's suppressible.

I added `#pragma warning(disable : 4984)` before my `if constexpr` expression, and found the legacy project can compile and operate well, so do I need to worry about the "portable" things?

Comment: if constexpr exists only in c++17 onwards. you mentioned that your project is c++14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if constexpr` is a C++17 feature. It can't be used in C++14. If a compiler is allowing it in C++14 mode (with a warning), then this is as an extension. Other compilers, especially older ones, will not do so.

`#pragma warning(disable : 4984)` is certainly not portable. It is MSVC-specific.